# Get disks attached to stopped instances using python sdk

Tags: azure, azure-disk

I am working on azure python sdk, I trying get disks attached to instances in stopped state for eg disks attached to virtual machine in stopped state, I know `managedby` property will give me disks with no instances attached but i am not able to get any api or property to check whether a disks in currently in use or not.

**Is there any method to get disks attached to stopped instances like virtual machines?**

Comment: I'm not clear about your question. If the disks attached to a VM. Then the disk would be in use no matter the VM stop or run. So what do you really mean in the question?

Comment: he just dont know how to do that, thats it

Comment: ok @CharlesXu, Is there any method to get those disks?

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
# you can also list by subscription
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.disks_operations.disksoperations?view=azure-python#list-custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-
disks = compute_client.disks.list_by_resource_group('resourcegroupname')
for disk in disks:
    print disk
```

this will give you all the disks in the resource group. there is no way to get all the "orphan" disks. I think your best bet is getting all the disks and looking if they are attached to something

Additional examples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/wiki/Managed-Disk

Answer (score 1):

There no direct function to list the disks attached to a VM in the Python SDK, you can just list the managed disks by group or subscription. But you can get the disks attached to a VM in the VM property.

For example, you can list the data disks like this:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient

TENANT_ID = "xxxxx"
CLIENT_ID = "xxxxx"
KEY = "secret"

cred = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id = CLIENT_ID,
        secret = KEY,
        tenant = TENANT_ID)

subscription_id = "xxxxx"

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(cred, subscription_id)

rg = "resourceGroupName"
vm_name = "vmName"

vm_info = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(rg, vm_name)

for disk in vm_info.storage_profile.data_disks:
    print disk.managed_disk.id
```

Comment: what's the point of copying my answer, essentially? this doesn't add anything new

Comment: @4c74356b41 I don't think I copy your answer. You just list the managed disks by the group, not exactly the attached disks.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking all fields of object `disk` and i found that name of associated VM can be extracted from `name` field. for eg i found name `TestVM2_OsDisk_1_834968b1cdc341c78bfbc227c9ccacda` here `TestVM2` is name of vm with which disk is attached.

So, I am taking name of VM from `name` field by using regular expression `re.split('_OsDisk', disk.name)` and checking VM state using azure apis for VMs, if it gives me `VM deallocated` then it is in stopped state or it will give me `VM running`.

This may not be a good way, but this is working for now.

Comment: just a word of caution, only default named disks have this name. you can create a disk with any name and attach it to a vm with any name (as long as they are in the same region)

Comment: @VikasGautam You make me confused about what you want. The VM of a disk? Or the disks attached to a VM?